# text is not aligned in 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I have a row with 2 columns, where there is some text: [My Website Example](http://vouzalis.com/test.html). I do not understand why the text on the 2 columns is not aligned? The right side the text is flying more above, than the left side. They should be aligned.

How can that be?

There is a lot of CSS, so I did not copy the code in here. But there is a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ca6d4kt/).

```
<body>
  <table class="body">
    <tr>
      <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>
            <table class="row footer">
                <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">

                      <table class="six columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="left-text-pad">

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <strong>Detaljer om værelset:</strong>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 2
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 3
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <table class="six columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="left-text-pad">

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 1
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 2
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 3
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: The right side table division does not have padding top and right like in left side td where you have given class="wrapper".
Just give padding-topL10px on the right td and it will work.

Comment: you should start using the web inspector ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="body" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
                <table class="row footer">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper" valign="top">
                            <table class="six columns">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left-text-pad">
                                        <table>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="left-text-pad">
                                                    <h5>A Headline</h5>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <strong>Detaljer om værelset:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="left-text-pad">
                                                    <h5>A Headline</h5>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <table class="six columns">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left-text-pad">
                                        <h5>A Headline</h5>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left-text-pad">A content text 1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left-text-pad">
                                        <h5>A Headline</h5>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left-text-pad">A content text 2
                          
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class 'wrapper' has padding, but its only on the left table not the right

Answer (score 2):

```
you missed the class wrapper in the right column.Due to this the right side text is flying over.
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of padding you applied for `.wrapper` class.

Your actual code

`td.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}`

Replace with 
`td.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}`

Hope it works!

Comment: Look like it is working now. I can see when I reach 600px breakpoint the left column is getting very small, and the right side is bigger. How can I make that the 2 columns have the same size under 600px breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle, you put the `.wrapper` class only on the first `td` of the outer table. It has a padding-top of 10px which is what is causing the disalignment. So, either add the same class to the other td, or remove it, or remove the padding-top rule.

Comment: Ah yes I can see that. I have added a class now: http://vouzalis.com/test.html . But I can see when I reach 600px breakpoint the left column is getting very small, and the right side is bigger. How can I make that the 2 columns have the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the wrapper class. Remove content-wrapper class and put wrapper instead of it.

And also give a width size of table. So, you can find alignment.

It works.